how to change color of a google maps v3 Marker icon
I'm placing a series of google maps Markers on a page using an array of points and a circle as an icon.
Once all the markers are on the page, I want to change the fill color of one of the Marker circles. How do I identify, say, the third Marker in my series so I can make that change? And how do I change the fillColor? I'm not using a google map event to identify the marker.
let map;

async function initMap() {
    // The location of the point
    const position = { lat: 40.44396002705076, lng: -80.00466302883518 };
    const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
    const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
     
      // The map, centered at the point
    map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: position,
        mapId: "6366bc12ac68e27f",
        
    });

 var arrMuralPositions = [
    { lat: 40.44215080214157, lng: -80.00194178463394 }, //stop 1
    { lat: 40.44219643284648, lng: -79.99723183193605 },//stop 2
    { lat: 40.44147920270817, lng: -79.99549375400392 },//stop 3
];

var myLabel;
     for (var i = 0; i<arrMuralPositions.length; i++) {
        myLabel = i+1;
         new google.maps.Marker({
        //new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
            position: arrMuralPositions[i],
            label: {text: myLabel.toString(), color: "white"},
            icon: {
              path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
              scale: 10,
             // fillColor: "#D8896D",
              fillColor: "#376cb9",
              strokeColor: "#376cb9",
              fillOpacity: 1,
              strokeWeight: 1,
            },
            map: map,
          }); 
     }

}

initMap();

//now how do I change the fillColor of the second Marker that I placed?


To change the color of the marker, change it's icon's fill and stroke colors:
  function highlightMarker(marker) {
    var icon = marker.getIcon()
    icon.fillColor = "black";
    icon.strokeColor = "black";
    marker.setIcon(icon);
  }

To change the color back for this simple case, where they are all fixed to be the same, change it back to the original value:
  function unhighlightMarker(marker) {
    var icon = marker.getIcon();
    icon.fillColor = "#376cb9";
    icon.strokeColor = "#376cb9";
    marker.setIcon(icon);
  }

Simplest way to keep track of the markers is to add them to an array.
Related questions:

Google Maps API - show marker from select
how to set new color for legacy google map marker

proof of concept fiddle

code snippet:


let map
let gmarkers = []

async function initMap() {
  // The location of the point
  const position = {
    lat: 40.44396002705076,
    lng: -80.00466302883518
  }
  const {
    Map
  } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps")
  const {
    AdvancedMarkerElement,
    PinElement
  } =
  await google.maps.importLibrary("marker")

  // The map, centered at the point
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: position,
    mapId: "6366bc12ac68e27f",
  })

  var arrMuralPositions = [
    {lat: 40.44215080214157,lng: -80.00194178463394}, //stop 1
    {lat: 40.44219643284648,lng: -79.99723183193605}, //stop 2
    {lat: 40.44147920270817,lng: -79.99549375400392}, //stop 3
  ]

  var myLabel
  for (var i = 0; i < arrMuralPositions.length; i++) {
    myLabel = i + 1
    gmarkers.push(
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: arrMuralPositions[i],
        label: {
          text: myLabel.toString(),
          color: "white"
        },
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 10,
          // fillColor: "#D8896D",
          fillColor: "#376cb9",
          strokeColor: "#376cb9",
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeWeight: 1,
        },
        map: map,
      }),
    )
  }
  highlightMarker(gmarkers[1]);
  setTimeout(function() {
    unhighlightMarker(gmarkers[1])
  }, 5000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    highlightMarker(gmarkers[2])
  }, 10000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    unhighlightMarker(gmarkers[2])
  }, 15000);


  function highlightMarker(marker) {
    var icon = marker.getIcon()
    icon.fillColor = "black";
    icon.strokeColor = "black";
    marker.setIcon(icon);
  }


  function unhighlightMarker(marker) {
    var icon = marker.getIcon();
    icon.fillColor = "#376cb9";
    icon.strokeColor = "#376cb9";
    marker.setIcon(icon);
  }
}

initMap()
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Default Advanced Marker</title>

  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- prettier-ignore -->
  <script>
        (g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "weekly"});
  </script>
</body>

</html>




One thing, the code works, but it throws the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getIcon')" for the unhighlightMarker function. Any idea why that might be?

Do you see that error in the code snippet above (or the jsfiddle)?  I don't.  Is your code the same as that in the code snippet (or in the answer above)?  Are you passing a google.maps.Marker object in to the function?
